# R- Check if string contains only certain patterns

Tags: r

I am trying to set up a table where the users can insert formulas in the form of a string.

They are allowed to use *only*  operators  and given par names (eg, `par.names<- c("P1", "P2", "P3")` )

I need to test if the formula is correct, by checking whether a user has used any other patterns.

For example `P1+P2*P3` should be acceptable, while `P1+P5*P$4` should return an error.

What would be the suggested way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, first, you define your variable names and then give a regular expression that would match your operators, then we can make a validater function

```
par.names<- c("P1", "P2", "P3")
operators <- "[*+]"

get_checker <- function(par.names, operatorsRE) {
  function(x) {
    nonops <- strsplit(x, operatorsRE)  
    sapply(nonops, function(x) all(x %in% par.names))
  }
}

checker <- get_checker(par.names, operators)
```

We just use an enclosure to keep everything in a tidy function. Then we can use that to validate input

```
input <- c("P1+P2*P3", "P1+P5*P$4")
checker(input)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Here's a version that will allow you to pass an array of operators instead.

```
par.names<- c("P1", "P2", "P3")
operators <- c("^", "*","+")

get_checker <- function(par.names, operators) {
  operatorsRE <- paste0("(", paste(Hmisc::escapeRegex(operators), collapse="|"),")")
  function(x) {
    nonops <- strsplit(x, operatorsRE)  
    sapply(nonops, function(x) all(x %in% par.names))
  }
}
```

That way you can avoid regular expression quirks but this does use the `Hmisc` package for a helper function.

Comment: one slight improvement if OP has no knowledge whatsoever about regex is to take the operators as string then `paste0` the brackets

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk. That still could be dangerous if they did something like "^*+". I'm not sure if there's a function that will automatically escape "special" character in a regular expression, but if one exists that is a good idea.

Comment: if you `paste0('[\\', operators, ']')` would work even if the first operator is `+` or `*` ....

Comment: following your edit better use `collapse=''` as they're already inside a character class

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk I just changed it from a character class to a group to allow for multi-character operators like `%%` or something. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: sorry, I thought you used brackets

Answer (score 2):

create a vector which holds strings of valid characters:

```
Allowed = c("+","-","*", "/","P","n","X")
```

write a function to check if any of the characters in the command are not allowed:

```
Vcheck = function(string){
  temp = strsplit(string, "")
  (((temp %in% Allowed) %>% sum) == length(temp))  %>% return 
}
```

This should return 1 if it contains allowed character, and 0 if it contains a forbidden one. I trust you know how to write a function to return an error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What should the split argument in  strsplit be? Also, do you think this will work for Allowed items with length >1 (eg "P1")?

Comment: @emantz the argument is the command which your user gave as input - for example if the user gave the string ` "P1+P2/2"`, you enter it into the function, and thats it.

Comment: @emantz I also just noticed I missed a bracket, now its fixed.

Comment: I meant the split argument in strsplit(string): Error in strsplit(string) : argument "split" is missing, with no default

Comment: I think I need to add [[1]] after temp, since it is a list: So, it works but only with Allowed elements of 1 character. For example, with Allowed = c("+","-","*", "/","P1","n","X"), 
Vcheck(string="X+P1"), will return FALSE.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
all(unlist(strsplit(s,"[^[:alnum:]]")) %in% par.names)
```

Example

```
> s1 <- "P1+P2*P3"

> s2 <- "P1+P5*P$4"

> all(unlist(strsplit(s1,"[^[:alnum:]]")) %in% par.names)
[1] TRUE

> all(unlist(strsplit(s2,"[^[:alnum:]]")) %in% par.names)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: note that this will return `TRUE` for `s <- "P1+P2$P3"` maybe if you change the split param to only contain operator then this case will fail ie `strsplit(s,"[/+*]")`